# Is it possible to pattern the outside of an open polygon?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pattern

I read [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/183893/27256) and learnt about the pattern command.

My question is simply the following: given the scenario in the linked answer, is it possible to generate the same pattern on the other side of the boundary? I.e. have only the area in blue with a pattern:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass[border={1mm 1mm 1mm 1mm}]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]
\draw[->] (-4.5,0) -- (1.5,0);
\draw[->] (0,-4.5) -- (0,4.5);
\foreach \x in {-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1}
    \draw (\x cm,1.5pt) -- (\x cm,-1.5pt);
\foreach \y in {-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4}
    \draw (1.5pt,\y cm) -- (-1.5pt,\y cm);
    \draw[thick,red,pattern=north east lines,pattern color=red] (-4,-4) -- (0,0)--(-4,4);
\draw[draw=none,red,pattern=north west lines,pattern color=blue] (0,0)--(-4,4) to[in=150,out=0] (4,2)--(4,-2)to[in=0,out=200](-4,-4) --(0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is the result:

[image]

If you consider the last line code, you can easily customize the boundaries of outer area.